# Lua - Combining two variables

Tags: lua, roblox

What I am trying to do is create a new variable (let's call it 'C') from adding a string ('Apple') to another variable ('84').
How do I do this?

Example

```
A = 'Apple'
B = 84
C = 'Apple(84)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local C = string.format("%s(%i)", A, B)
```

See the [reference](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format) for more information on `string.format`

or, in simple cases like that, you can also just do

```lua
local C = A .. "(" .. tostring(B) .. ")"
```